# Editing several excel files before after iterating through path folder - python

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm working on editing several Excel files at once and when it comes time to iterate through all of my folders, it is only capable of doing so for the first .xlsx file.

```py
def sumOfCosts():
    path=os.chdir(r'C:\Users\salvarai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\COSTBOMS')
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            wb=load_workbook(filename=file)
            sheet=wb.active()
            sheet['08'].value="Total Cost="
                                     
            char=get_column_letter(8)
            sumchar=get_column_letter(16)
            sheet[sumchar+"8"]=F"=SUM({char+'2'}:{char +'1000'})"
            wb.save(file)
            wb.close()
        return
```

Comment: You can post code blocks using 3 back ticks, ie ``` to start and end the block.  What testing have you done to isolate the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your return statement on the same indent level as the '**if file.endswith(".xlsx"):**' so regardless of the statements in the if condition being executed the 'return' statement will be on the first 'file'.
To keep iterating thru the files move the 'return' to be level with the line '**for file in os.listdir(path)**' so the function does not return until all the 'file's are processed.

```
def sumOfCosts():
    path = os.chdir(r'C:\Users\salvarai\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\COSTBOMS')
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            wb = load_workbook(filename=file)
            sheet = wb.active()
            sheet['08'].value = "Total Cost ="

            char = get_column_letter(8)
            sumchar = get_column_letter(16)
            sheet[sumchar + "8"] = F"=SUM({char+'2'}:{char +'1000'})"

            wb.save(file)
            wb.close()
    return  # <--- The return should be at this indent level
```